# spaCy language module not downloading

Tags: python, anaconda, spacy

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04. I downloaded spaCy using conda and am working on jupyter notebook.
I tried

```
python -m spacy download en
```

which gives the following error:

/home/nikita/anaconda3/bin/python: No module named spacy.**main**; 'spacy' is a package and cannot be directly executed

So I tried

```
python -m spacy.en.download
```

which gives these errors:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))

File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

 File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output self.send(msg)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send self.connect()
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1392, in connect super().connect()
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 936, in connect(self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection raise err
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main  "__main__", mod_spec)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/en/download.py", line 13, in <module  plac.call(main)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 328, in call  cmd, result = parser.consume(arglist)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plac_core.py", line 207, in consume  return cmd, self.func(*(args + varargs + extraopts), **kwargs)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/en/download.py", line 9, in main   download('en', force)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spacy/download.py", line 24, in download   package = sputnik.install(about.__title__, about.__version__, about.__models__[lang])
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/__init__.py", line 37, in install  index.update()
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/index.py", line 84, in update index = json.load(session.open(request, 'utf8'))
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/session.py", line 43, in open    r = self.opener.open(request)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open    response = self._open(req, data)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open    '_open', req)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain    result = func(*args)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused
Exception ignored in: <bound method Session.__del__ of <sputnik.session.Session object at 0x7f30d010d828
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sputnik/session.py", line 58, in __del__
File "/home/nikita/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/http/cookiejar.py", line 2070, in save
NameError: name 'open' is not defined
```

Then I tried

```
python3 -m spacy.en.download --force all
```

which gives the same errors as the 2nd one.
Please help!

Comment: Please copy paste the errors here so that we can take a look. It isn't possible to figure out what is wrong without the error messages.

Comment: Sorry...I have edited my question now..Please help!

Comment: Hmm, it looks like you have an old version of spaCy installed – was that intentional? And did you install spaCy via conda? You can try explicitly installing the latest version like this: `conda install -c conda-forge spacy=2.0.11`.

Comment: @InesMontani Thank you soooo much !!! It worked!

Comment: Yay, glad it worked! I'll post an official answer so you can accept it (in case others come across the same problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, conda seems to have installed an older version of spaCy. To make sure you're installing the latest version (or any other specific one), you can use the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy=2.0.11
```

(Disclaimer: I'm one of the spaCy maintainers. We're still investigating why this happens to some users, and whether it's related to how dependencies are resolved, an old Anaconda distribution that ships with spaCy `0.101.0` or something entirely different. The relevant thread on the issue tracker is [here](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2462).)

Comment: Thank you! :D 
However, after I installed it this way it said: The following packages will be REMOVED:    anaconda:        5.2.0-py36_3
Then when I went to load the module it gave me more errors ..I don't know if its related..
If you could please help here :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51040834/error-while-loading-english-module-in-spacy